# Drupal 8 - "Level up" link in taxonomy term view

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

this is my first question on Drupal Answers so... nice to meet you :)

On Drupal 8 site I've replaced default taxonomy term page for one of my vocabularies with composition of view and block. View shows a table with nodes tagged with taxonomy term from the URL. Block contains a view with taxonomy term's children. These two components together have a feeling of files explorer application (like Finder, Explorer or Nautilus). But one thing is missing - a link to the parent taxonomy term. Name it "level up" or sth. 
I've tried adding something to the footer of block's view but with no results. And didn't find anything on the internet. Do you know if there is any possibility of doing this?

PS: I know that there is breadcrumb on every page, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: you can use views field view module to display the parent of child terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would just write a custom code:

- You will need to define a custom block
- And you will also need to get the parameter from the URL.
- You will need the "database" service (select) in your code, to query the parent term (if there is any).